# Scheduling jobs/tasks in PHP

Tags: php, queue, task, jobs, schedule

I have a small basic website written in PHP to service a small number of users.
The website is Windows-based (IIS) and interacts with a Windows application on behalf of a user.

From clicking a confirm button, the process can take up to 30 seconds.
My problem is, the website must deal with each user individually and only ever one at a time. There are only a small number of users making a small number of requests per day.

I would like to add jobs to a queue and then process each job one at a time while there are jobs in the queue.

Many solutions I have come across seem like overkill for what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a simple/native way of achieving this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thirty seconds is a long time; is the windows app that slow or does your code need to be refactored?  At any rate, you could create a database table to store user input. Add a couple of timestamp fields (created and finished). Make a CLI script to take the user input stored in the database (null finished timestamp), process it, and update the finished field in the database.  The CLI script can be run by either the webpage or a scheduled task or both.

Comment: Thirty seconds is excessive, hence why I need some sort of worker script to process it instead of making the user wait. 
I was thinking of using a database to store the data, but I asked to see if I was missing something obvious.
Thanks for the reply Tim, appriciated!